# FileMaker Pro 12 Checkbox Formatting - checked values not recognizable

Tags: filemaker

I sometimes have 20 or more values ​​within in a single check box. It is then not easy to see which value is checked. Has anyone an idea how I can improve the readability? Maybe through a special formatting? I want either the cross to be better visible, or the text behind the very cross to be marked, somehow.!
[FileMaker Checkbox - checked values not recognizable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpQa7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a edit box version of the field (I'll call it `MyTable::MyOptions`) next to the checkbox and remove the ability to edit the field in browse mode. That way, each time a user checks or unchecks a value, the edit box version of the field would show each unique value selected.

Aside from that, you could also consider changing the field that holds the checkbox to a portal that points to a "Checkbox Options" table that holds all of the possible options. You could put a button on each portal row that runs a script "add/remove option" that

- Takes the value from the currently clicked portal row
- Compares it to your field that you used to have your check box on to see if the value exists or not:

  `PatternCount ( ¶ & MyTable::MyOptions & ¶  ; ¶ & $selectedValue & ¶ ) > 0`
- If the value does exist already (the pattern count returns true) then you could remove the value from the list:

  `Substitute ( ¶ & MyTable::MyOptions & ¶ ; ¶ & $selectedValue & ¶ ; ¶ )`
- If the value does not exist, you could append it to the field:

  `Set Field [MyTable::MyOptions ; MyTable::MyOptions & ¶ & $selectedValue]`

This would allow you to add conditional formatting to the button on each portal row to change color if the value the row holds is in the field containing all of your options.